# store.findAll strange behavior

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code in a controller:

```
ingredients: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.store.findAll('ingredient').then(function() {
        var ingredients = self.get('model').get('ingredientsWithQuantities').map(function(item) {
            return {
                name: self.store.peekRecord('ingredient', item.ingredientId).get('name'), 
                quantity: item.quantity
            };
        });

        self.set('ingredients', ingredients);
    });
}.property('model.ingredientsWithQuantities')
```

It's a computed property related to one of the routes. It works fine if ***'ingredients'*** model is loaded somewhere earlier. But if it's loading for the first time, when `then` function is called there is no data in the store.

I was expecting that `findAll` would call `then` only after data was fetched. How can I handle this?

**UPDATE:**

When I add `shouldReloadAll() { return true; }` to my application RestAdapter it works fine except one thing. It actually reloads always even if data exists. But I need just one request of this type during user's session.

It is possible to achieve the next behavior?

*when data doesn't exist in the store* - then load data and call function after it

*when data exists in the store* - then just call function

Comment: Does `this.store.findAll('ingredient', { reload: true }).then(....` work?

Answer (score 1):

`this.store.findAll('ingredient')`will return all `ingredients` in the store and then it will update it with a request to the *backend*, or that's how I think it works but I'm not sure why it isn't working like that.

A solution is to use `this.store.query` which will make a request to the `backend`for sure.

Example:

```
return this.store.query('ingredient', { filter: { } }).then(function(result) {
        // do something with the result
    });
```

Comment: So if there are no data in the store, findAll just will return empty array?

Comment: If there is no data in the store `findAll` will make a request and return all the results. I can't tell you why or how since I don't know but that's how it works right now.